# Cannot replace a string with several random strings taken from another table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to replace a placeholder string inside a selection of **10 random records** with a **random string** (a name) taken from another table, using only sqlite statements.

i've done a subquery in order to replace() of the placeholder with the results of a subquery. I thought that each subquery loaded a random name from the names table, but i've found that it's not the case and each placeholder is replaced with the same string.

```
select id, (replace (snippet, "%NAME%", (select 
name from names 
where gender = "male"
) )
) as snippet 
from imagedata
where timestamp is not NULL
order by random()
limit 10
```

I was expecting for each row of the SELECT to have different random replacement every time the subquery is invoked.

- hello i'm %NAME% and this is my house
- This is the car of %NAME%, let me know what you think

instead each row has the same kind of replacement:

- hello i'm **david** and this is my house
- This is the car of **david**, let me know what you think
- and so on...

I'm not sure it can be done inside sqlite or if i have to do it in php over two different database queries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `random()` in the subquery is only evaluated once.
Try this:

```
select 
  i.id,
  replace(i.snippet, '%NAME%', n.name) snippet
from (
  select 
    id, 
    snippet, 
    abs(random()) % (select count(*) from names where gender = 'male') + 1 num 
  from imagedata 
  where timestamp is not NULL
  order by random() limit 10
) i inner join (
  select 
    n.name,
    (select count(*) from names where name < n.name and gender = 'male') + 1 num 
  from names n  
  where gender = 'male'
) n on n.num = i.num
```

Comment: i'm still having the same issue, to clarify: if i request a single row from the table "imagedata" every request get a proper replacement.
But otherwise, if i request 10 rows at the time, all the rows get the same replacement from the "names" table.

Comment: @GarethJax The issue is that that subquery is only evaluated once, because it doesn't depend on the values of the current row of the main query.

Comment: Yes I'm checking it now. I will try to find a workaround.

Comment: i'm still having the same issue, even with the last version of the query.

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/js8boledcisbcsp/Screenshot%202019-04-18%2018.31.57.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: @forpas it works and a it's beautiful code, now could you explain to me how it works? :)

Comment: I created number columns in each table based on the number of rows of the table `names` and joined them. The numbers in the snippet table are random.